# How does cost function with abs value(= no gradient direction) works?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

0
down vote
favorite
I am a novice in the topic and as for me, if we are optimizing some function with gradient descent we need to know how much we missed(gradient magnitude) and the direction of gradient + or - sign.

Let say we have y = w*x. And we have a weight W = 4; x = 3; So we got y = 4*3 = 12. For example, the target value y in x = 3 point is 6. So if we have cost function without ABS we will have gradient = 6 - 12 = -6. And so we can say that should adjust W by -6/3 = -2. So target W will be 4 - 2 = 2. Bingo.

From the other side if we will use some abs cost function like square loss we will not have a direction of miss. We will not know are we overshoot or undershoot, should we reduce W in this example or make it bigger. Can you please explain how gradient optimization works for this case?

Comment: Quick question:  I don't undestand "the target value $y$ in $x=3$ point is 6" since that seems to contradict your previous sentence concluding "$y=12$."  How can $y=6$ and $y=12$ both be true?

Comment: Overall, what do you mean by "target value" and what do you mean by "we should adjust"?  What is the goal here?

Comment: y=12 is current value with W=4. We should adjust  W to force Y return 6 for x=3 (Y will be 6 if w=2 for x=3).

Comment: Why should we adjust $W$ to force $Y$ to return 6?

Comment: Overall it sounds like you are giving a fuzzy description of some type of algorithm using loaded terminology that you think brings meaning to your problem.  If you want to minimize the function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = |wx|$, where $w$ is a given real number, and you want to use subgradients, one simple algorithm is $x_{t+1}=x_t - f'(x_t)\eta$ where $\eta$ is a small stepsize, and $f'(x_t)$ is any subgradient at the point $x_t$.  You indeed might "overshoot" your target minimum $x^*=0$ but if you use a small enough step size, that overshoot is limited.